# Printing part of an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a quick question.

I just want to print parts of an integer. For example, my integer is today's date: 20190327 
...and I would like to print the "03" part.

Is this even possible with integers?

I would like to do something similar to this:

```
todays_date = 20190327
print(todays_date[0:5])
```

But this doesn't work.
Is there a simple solution?
Thanks!

Comment: `str(todays_date)[0:5]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
todays_date = '20190327'
print(todays_date[0:5])
```

You just needed to ensure `todays_date` was a string. Putting quotes around this does that. Alternatively, if you would still like to use `todays_date` as an integer, you can convert it to a string just for the print statement:

```
todays_date = 20190327
print(str(todays_date)[0:5])
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!